# sorting the dictionary by its key values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which elements needs to be sorted by its "keys". and print it line by line. For eg:

```
dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio", "jackson":"mississippi",
  "phoenix":"arizona"}
```

Output should be:

```
columbus:ohio  
indianapolis:indiana  
jackson:mississippi  
phoenix:arizona
```

Something like:

```
def sortdic(d):
    keys = d.keys()
    keys.sort()
    return keys

for k in sortdic(d):
    print k, v
```

But the constraints are that only `sorted()`, `split()` functions should be used and no other built-in function should be used (like `keys()`, `values()`, `items()`,`lambda`). I am still learning python and new to dictionary and any code would be helpful for me to learn it.

Comment: This is the 4th question you've asked about `dict` with silly constraints... are you taking time to understand any of the answers given, or are you purely copy/pasting into new questions each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dictionary's keys as an iterator using `iterkeys()`:

```
for key in sorted(d.iterkeys()):
    print key, d[key]
```

Comment: You can only use `.sorted()` and `.split()`.